# two JDBC template objects in single class

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I am working on application created using spring framework. In DAO implementation class, we are using `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` to create the object and connect to database.Below is the code.

```
 @Inject
    @Qualifier("jdbcTemplateServiceATW)
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

Can i create another `JdbcTemplate` object in the same class as i want to connect to other table which is in another schema. So i need a new `JdbcTemplate object`.
Can i have **two `JdbcTemplate` objects** created in the same class as shown below.

```
 @Inject
    @Qualifier("jdbcTemplateServiceATW)
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Inject
    @Qualifier("jdbcTemplateServiceDLW")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateMyLoans;
```

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with 2 different databases using 2 JdbcTemplates you can do as follows:

**Configure DataSources, JdbcTemplates and TransactionManagers as follows:**

```
<bean id="dataSource1" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"></property>
    <property name="url" value="${node1.jdbc.url}"></property>
    <property name="username" value="${node1.jdbc.username}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${node1.jdbc.password}"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource2" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"></property>
    <property name="url" value="${node2.jdbc.url}"></property>
    <property name="username" value="${node2.jdbc.username}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${node2.jdbc.password}"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2"></property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txnManager1"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txnManager2"/>

<bean id="txnManager1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
</bean>

<bean id="txnManager2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
</bean>
```

You can inject multiple JdbcTemplates and use them, but you need to declare correct TransactionManager to use with @Transactional based on which JdbcTemplate you are using.

```
@Service
public class MyService
{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jdbcTemplate1")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate1;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jdbcTemplate2")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate2;

    @Transactional("txnManager1")
    public void method1()
    {
        //do something with jdbcTemplate1
    }

    @Transactional("txnManager2")
    public void method2()
    {
        //do something with jdbcTemplate2
    }
}
```

Comment: could not able to access the database table. Showing exception as : nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist .

Answer (score 0):

You can have any number of Spring configured beans in class, but if you want data from two databases, you must have two JdbcTemplate classes configured with two different DataSource objects.
In addition, you can use annotation `@Resource` which autowires bean by name and not by class.

For example:

```
@Resource
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateServiceATW;
@Resource
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateServiceDLW;
```